# iPhone app lag on startup before main

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I launch the app on my [3GS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_3GS) it sits on the Default.png for 4-5 seconds. I'm not sure what it is doing during this time. I placed NSLog timing statements at the top of `main` and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The NSLog statement from main does not print to the console until the moment that Default.png goes away, and the entire process from the top of main to the bottom of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions only takes 1 second.

So, what is my app doing before it starts `main`, and what can I do to speed that time up?

Comment: Can you learn more from Instruments?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how I would go about doing that to investigate this problem. This is only my second "real" app and I have not run into a problem like this before.

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but I've seen similar lag starting up any app - mine or from the app store - on my 3GS on iOS 4.

Answer (score 1):

Don't start from Xcode with a debugger, that takes a lot of time. You will see that your app starts much faster when you launch it via the icon on your homescreen.

Comment: Some more information about what's happening in that time might be available from the Activity window.  It is available from the Window menu item in xcode.  Similarly, the Organizer window can sometimes give you a progress meter if files are being copied to the device.

Comment: The 4-5 second duration is actually launching it directly from the icon on the phone. It takes a few seconds longer (as you mention) when using Xcode.

Comment: Okay, then please ignore my answer. Didn't knew that you started it via the homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at your plist file and xib files (not 100% sure if root view gets loaded before or after main, but worth a shot). Also, how big is that png file? Try launching without it and see how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application do this even when there are no other programs resident in memory?   The reason that I ask:  since you have observed that the delay appears to happen prior to entering `main()`, then it is possible that iOS believes that more memory is needed in order to run your program.   If there are other apps in the `Suspended` state, then iOS could be busy waking those apps up momentarily in order to invoke `didReceiveMemoryWarning` on their view controllers, and perhaps ultimately tell them to go away by calling their app delegate's `applicationWillTerminate:`.   Perhaps this is what is taking time.

One easy test you could perform would be to completely reboot your phone and then launch your app a few times without running anything else first.  After the first invokation of your app, I would expect it to start quickly (unless your app, itself, allocates a lot of memory!).

If you didn't want to reboot your phone, you could [manually remove all of the apps from your multi-tasking switcher](http://www.callingallgeeks.org/iphone-tip-how-to-force-quit-a-frozen-application/) by closing each one by touching the red minus signs that you can bring up using touch-and-hold.   Then run your app and see if you are still seeing the 4-to-5 second delay.